# .NET instant out of scope notification?

Tags: .net, scope

In .NET, is there a simple way for a class to be notified as it falls out of scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with some languages. C++/CLI will emit Dipose calls for IDisposable implementers when their non-heap allocations drop out of scope (effectively giving them the same semantics as stack allocated resource in normal C++). Moreover, C++/CLI destructor syntax of ~Classname becomes an implementation of Dispose (and makes the class implement IDisposable).

I would expect other languages with traditional deterministic destruction to adopt this policy as time goes on. As others have mentioned, you can emulate it in C# with "using", but it's not quite the same.

Answer (score 3):

No.

If you need to clean up resources other than memory, implement IDisposable and create your objects with `using` blocks.  If you need to clean up memory, you really can leave it to the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

If it implements IDisposable and you're using a using block, sure.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no deterministic finalization in any .NET language.  The garbage collector is responsible for finalizing objects that have no roots in the application.

Comment: He wasn't asking about finalization though, he was asking about being notified. 

And as for it not being available in any .NET language, if you program in C++/CLI (the successor to Managed C++ which first appeared in VS2005), you can declare a reference to an object as if it were an auto variable. If that object's class implements IDisposable it will be notified when it goes out of scope. This is a feature sadly missing from C# IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If it implements IDisposable, your Dispose() method would find out:

```
using (var c = new YourClassImplementsIDisposable() )
{
    // Stuff happens
}
// c.Dispose has been called
```

otherwise no, because your object is just 'hanging out' until GC

Answer (score 0):

You could use a finalizer.  It would be called once garbage colelcted, but not immediately after leaving scope.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-object-finalizers